# Excel VBA code running while debugging and not in normal mode

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim DateFrom As Object
Set DateFrom = IE.Document.getElementByID("XXXXXX")
If Not DateFrom Is Nothing Then
DateFrom.Value = "1234"
End If
```

When I debug from `Set DateFrom` step it inputs value to textbox on ie webpage but when running in normal mode it does not?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not waiting for the page to completely load. This isn't really enough of the code to give an answer though.

Comment: Was going to say the same as @Comintern, you could add an else case to your if statement to check this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.